# RequestMapping массив строк

Tags: java, json, spring

Есть такой json, который приходит с фронта, внутри которого массив строк

```
[{"datebirth"="2022-02-01T00:00"},{"datebirth"="2022-02-01T00:00"}]
```

мне на бэке нужно его как-то принять и превратить в массив строк (может в ДТО), чтобы получить возраст этих людей, исходя из дат рождения.  Как быть?

```java
public ResponseEntity <><Object> Calculate(
    @RequestBody List<InsuredDTO> insuredDTO // если не ДТО принимать, тогда что? Как парсить?
    ) {
// ...
}
```

Заранее благодарю

Comment: в примере приведён не json. Но если вы ошиблись в вопросе и это на самом деле json, то принимать его можно как `List<ВашКласс>`, где в ВашКласс вы создаёте атрибут `datebirth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JSON ключи и значения разделены двоеточием `:`, а не знаком равенства `=`.

Если принять, что данная строка всё-таки представляет корректный JSON, то она может быть автоматически преобразована в список объектов, то есть по большому счёту задача сводится к написанию DTO класса, например, при помощи `@Data` аннотации проекта Lombok (или же сгенерировать методы доступа, метод `toString` самостоятельно):

```java
@Data
public class AgeDto {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    private LocalDate datebirth;
}
```

Получить возраст из даты рождения можно так:

```java
public int getAge(LocalDate) {
    return Period.between(datebirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
}
```

Так что список `AgeDto` можно вывести в таком виде:

```java
// String json = "[{\"datebirth\":\"1980-09-07T00:00\"},{\"datebirth\":\"2000-01-01T00:00\"}]";

List<AgeDto> input = ...;//
input.stream()
     .forEach(dto -> System.out.printf("DOB: %s, age=%d yrs%n",
         dto.getDatebirth(), getAge(dto.getDatebirth())
     ));
// -> DOB: 1980-09-07, age: 41 yrs
// -> DOB: 2000-01-01, age: 22 yrs
```

---

Для возврата какого-то общего результата:

```java
public int getCalculation(List<AgeDto> ages) {
    return ages.stream()
        .mapToInt(AgeDto::getAge) // IntStream
        .map(age -> age < 18 ? 200 : 100)
        .sum();        
}
```

Или же при помощи цикла:

```java
public int getCalculation(List<AgeDto> ages) {
    int result = 0;
    for (AgeDto dto : ages) {
        result += dto.getAge() < 18 ? 200 : 100;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, многое помогло. Сделал такой вот класс
Data
Component
public class AgeDTO {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    public LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    public int getAge() {return Period.between(this.dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
у меня нет стримов. Вот сервисный слой:
    InsuredDTO insuredDTO;
    private int age = insuredDTO.getAge();

    Transactional
    public double getCalculation(List<AgeDTO> ageDTO) {
        return ?????????
    }

Answer (score -1):

Большое спасибо, многое помогло. Сделал такой вот класс

```
@Data
@Component
public class AgeDTO {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    public LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    public int getAge() {
        return Period.between(this.dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
```

у меня нет стримов. Вот сервисный слой:

```
AgeDTO ageDTO;
private int age = insuredDTO.getAge();

@Transactional
public double getCalculation(List<AgeDTO> ageDTO) {
    return ?????????
}
```

мне нужно как то здесь пройтись по всем объектам в листе - высчитать их возраст. Например если возраст больше 18 - возвращаем 100, если меньше 18 - возвращаем 200. Потом складываем полученные цифры и возвращаем int результат

Comment: в java есть циклы, например, `for`

Comment: См. обновлённый ответ.  Если вы не работаете с базой в методе `getCalculation`, а только со списком DTO, то аннотация `@Transactional` не нужна.